# I don't understand the concept of Ruby operators. What is the difference between '<' and 'xyz' method?

Tags: ruby, operators

```
class Computation

  def initialize(&block)
    @action = block
  end

  def result
    @result ||= @action.call
  end

  def xyz(other)

  end

  def <(other)
    result < other.result
  end


end

a = Computation.new { 1 + 1 }
b = Computation.new { 4*5 }



p a < b  #=> true
p a xyz b #=> `<main>': undefined method `xyz' for main:Objec
```

I don't understand why '<' method works properly and 'xyz' method returns error ?

Comment: You forgot the dot: `p a.xyz b => nil`

Comment: That's the question why I don't need '.' to call '<' method and why I need '.' to call 'xyz' method.

Comment: I assume you meant def `xyz() result < other.result end`.  (Parens only because I wrote it on one line.)

Comment: Think of it this way.  In Ruby, methods are sent to a receiver like this: `receiver.method`.  It is only for some methods that Ruby provides "syntactic sugar" to allow you to dispense with the dot.  In fact, `a < b` is invoked `a.<(b)`, `<` being the method.

Comment: Syntax is not absolute thing. It depends on context. `<` is not a valid method name character. It's just a language feature that makes things more convenient, e.g. ability to redefine operator easily. It's like `"a"*3 # => "aaa"`, it can be logical, can be non-logical, but is some way is very useful when you know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

in Ruby `< > + -` etc are operators, you can call operators without the dot, and off course you can redefine those operators (what you are doing here).

In the case of `xyz` is a string, and when called without the dot ruby treats it differently.

`a.xyz b` evaluates to `a.xyz(b)`

`a xyz b` evaluates to `a(xyz(b))` and since the global scope is `Object`, will throw `undefined method 'xyz' for main:Object`